# Program Calculating The Logs of Primes

Tags: python, math

Mathematical rule shows that my "program" gives a wrong answer.

I would be very grateful if you could check this small piece of code and tell me the problem with it. I know that the problem is somewhere after the line `ll = []`. I just can't pinpoint the exact cause of it. But I do know that *the sum of the logarithms of all the primes less than n is is less than n*. My program violates this rule.

Here is the code:

```
from math import log
lp = [] ## create a list
for n in range(2,10000):
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n % x == 0:
            break
    else:
        lp.append(n) ## fill that list with the primes
##print lp[500] found the value of lp[500]
ll = [] ## create a second list
for i in range(2, lp[500]):
        if i < 3581: ## this is the number corresponding to lp[500]
            i = log(i, )
            ll.append(i) ## fill the second list with logs of primes
print sum (ll), 3581, sum(ll)/3581`
```

Comment: How long does it take to calculate primes up to 10000? With one half-line change I can calculate them in 0.11s. Just change `for x in range(2,n):` to `for x in lp:`. If you want to go another magnitude faster, stop at the square root of n. Try to understand these two little changes before implementing them. So same algorithm, just a little bit optimized: https://gist.github.com/1347515 (the third change, step set to 2, doesn't add that much).

Answer (score 6):

Your second list doesn't only contain the logs of primes, it contains the logs of all integers between 2 and `lp[500]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
for i in range(2, lp[500]): ## Gives all numbers from 2 to lp[500]
    if i < 3581:
        i = log(i, ) ## this changes i which is your loop variable!
        ll.append(i)
```

Should be:

```
for i in range(501): ## from 0 to 500
  ll.append( log(lp[i],) )
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `i=log(i,)` will use the natural logarithm (e), where you may be interested in `log10(i)` (log with base=10).
see http://docs.python.org/library/math.html section 9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Build in doc says:

```
>>> from math import log
>>> log?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Base Class: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:<built-in function log>
Namespace:  Interactive
Docstring:
log(x[, base])

Return the logarithm of x to the given base.
If the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.
```